# Quad-only topology at the edge of a chamfer

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology, geometry

Is there a better way to recreate this shape using only quads?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I've been modelling in Blender for 10 years now and I know and follow the "quads-only-mantra". I have come across situations like this where I would add a 4. vertex into a triangle just like you did. Now: The quads are only important for texturing (much easier to follow the loops for seams) and modifiers like subsurf. In hard surface modelling I don't see any reason to go out of your way to avoid triangles. I don't post this as an answer, because it's my personal opinion.

Comment: While I agree that quad absolutism is unnecessary, in hard surface modeling there may not be much subdiv but there are usually a lot of bevels and boolean operations and both those often require cleaning up ngons and poles, no? You have a lot more experience than me so perhaps I'm missing something. Did you mean something different than what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a vertex at the middle of the triangle. You will need an extra edge loop at each of the horizontal and vertical edges.

[image]